# How to exclude one textbox from the others that are using isNumeric validation with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I'm using jQuery 1.11x in a jsp page with textboxes.  I'm working with five text boxes and I need to make sure they all have numeric entries,
however, I want to exclude the first one as it has a string representation of a date in it and I validate that one by it's id or some other way if it will guarantee uniqueness.

The code below checks all of the textboxes and fails on the one with the string date value, even if all the other textboxes have numbers.  The date format is dd/mm/yyyy.

```
if(!$.isNumeric($('input:text').val())) {
        alert("All the text boxes must have numeric values!");
        return false;
    }
```

I couldn't get the above code to work with :not, so I tried this selector, but it also failed to work.

```
if(!$.isNumeric($('input[type=checkbox]:not("#specialTextBox")').val())) {
        alert("All the text boxes must have numeric values!");
        return false;
    }
```

How do I exclude that particular textbox with the string date,but still validate the others all have numbers?

Comment: Try `'input:checkbox:not("#specialTextBox")'` Also you would need .each()

Comment: I don't have any checkboxes, just textboxes on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop all the textboxes

Take a look of jquery [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function here.

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("id") !== 'specialTextBox') {
       if(!$.isNumeric($(this).val()))
       {
         alert("All the text boxes must have numeric values!");
         return false;
       }
    }
});
```